# Datos del JWT disponibles en clases externas diferentes al controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

La funcionalidad para generar un token `JWT` trabaja perfectamente dentro del controlador de autenticación de los usuarios . Sin embargo, al intentar leer los datos del token por fuera del controlador en una clase externa no están disponibles.

Este el código de mi Starup.cs:

```
(C# .Net Core web api 3.1.)
```

```
public class Startup  
{  
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)  
{  
Configuration = configuration;  
}  

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddCors(options => {
options.AddPolicy("CorsPoliciy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().Build());
});

string defaultconecction = "Data Source=SQL5041.site.net;Initial Catalog=DB_A441E7_database;User Id=DB_A441E7_usuario_admin;Password=123;";

services.AddDbContext<UndbcontexDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(defaultconecction));

services.AddControllers();

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
ValidateIssuer = true,
ValidateAudience = true,
ValidateLifetime = true,
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
ValidIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Site"),
ValidAudience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Site"),
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtKey")))
};
});
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllers();
});
}
```

**Metodo que impelementa el token:**

```
private string Token(PreToken preToken)  
    {  
    var securitykey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey));
    SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(securitykey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var claims = new List<Claim>();  
    foreach (var item in preToken.Roles)  
    {  
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Roles.NombreRol));  
    }  

    claims.Add(new Claim("id", preToken.UsuarioId.ToString()));
    claims.Add(new Claim("correo", preToken.Email.ToString()));
    claims.Add(new Claim("empresa", preToken.EmpresaId.ToString()));

    JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Site"),
    audience: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Site"),
    claims,
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
    signingCredentials: credentials
    );

    var encodetoken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    return encodetoken;
    }
```

**el token es llamado de la siguiente manera en un IActionResult que maneja el login de usuarios:**

....

```
// llenamos el modelo del token  
PreToken preToken = new PreToken  
{
Email = consulta.Email,
EmpresaId = consulta.EmpresasId,
Roles = roles,
UsuarioId = consulta.Id,
Modulos = modulos
};

string token = Token(preToken);

return Ok(token);
```

**La forma cómo se leen los datos del token desde cualquier parte del controller es:**

```
// recuperamos la empresa del usuario  
var EmpresasId = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "empresa")?.Value;
```

**Esta lectura de una llave del token funciona perfectamente dentro del controller pero no funciona si la coloco en un clase externa**

> disculpen lo errores de novato al postear en su blog

Comment: Hola, indica por favor el código donde intentas *leer los datos del token por fuera del controlador en una clase externa*.

Comment: Ponga el método donde genera el token y el método que esta usando para obtener ese token. Ahí lo único que puso fue la configuración del startup pero no veo ningun método donde se genera el token???

Comment: Con base en su solicitud estoy posteando el método que implementa los token, la forma como se llama el método y la forma cómo se lee cualquier llave del token dentro del controller.

Comment: No tengo forma de probarlo por eso lo agrego como comentario, prueba esto: HttpContext.Current.User.Claims.... En tu clase pero ten en cuenta que solo funcionara si la ejecución de tu método es desencadenada por una petición del usuario. Y recuerda importar el namespace.

Comment: ¿Utilizas web api o mvc?

Comment: Estoy usando web api core 3.1.  Hice una prueba agregando una clase nueva y un  método en el cual coloque el HttpContext.Current y me sale un error que dice que HttpContext no contiene una definición para current. El HttpContext solo define Equals y Reference Equals

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el methodo `AddHttpContextAccessor` a la coleccion de servicios dentro de el metodo ConfigureServices de la clase `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

y luego lo podras acceder dentro de cualquiera de tus clases en el constructor

```
public MiServicio(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
```